# Microsoft Graph API /me/insights/used Not giving the Viewed Documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-graph

I am using the ms-graph API
As explained in the below link :-

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/used

The insights returns the most relevant documents that a user viewed or accessed. This includes documents in:

- OneDrive for Business
- SharePoint
  (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/insights_used)

But the results obatined from this query and the results seen in the Last Open Documents in the Offcie 365 Home Page are different.

*Below is the location of the last Open documents*

[image]

I don't see the Documents that i have only viewed. Is there another API? or is it because it is still under beta.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the exact same problem...

Comment: The same problem. Any updates?